# Search engine for a CMS

Tags: mysql, content-management-system, lucene, full-text-search, sphinx

I'm developing a search system for a CMS and we use INNODB. I'm still designing the system and at first i looked at FULLTEXT on mysql to develop the search feature but i just discovered it is supported by MyISAM only.

I've always ignored third party search engines like Lucene or Sphynx because i tought they couldn't adapt to a CMS because it had to be run externally from your webserver. I've never used one, that's why i'm asking a question: is there a third party search engine that could be easily deployed with the CMS code itself, without needing the user to run anything on the server?

Maybe the solution is easy but i'm totally new to these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Zend Framework's implementation of Lucene - it can be used standlone, without other parts of ZF, and it does not need separate server, since the search-index is stored in files.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's FULLTEXT searching is a very blunt instrument - and doesn't lend itself to refinement. If you want an off-the-shelf solution, you might want to have a look at [mnogo](http://www.mnogosearch.org/) which provides a lot of useful search engine functionality out of the box.

Comment: that's not what i need. i need to install it on the server and even compile it. I need something that doesn't need installation.

Comment: i did, it told me to ask on stackoverflow.

Comment: If you're not prepared to install something, then you're not going to get any better than MySQL's built-in FULLTEXT search. But as this answer states, that really isn't a particularly good tool.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try; http://www.google.co.uk/cse/

Otherwise depending on the complexity of the search perhaps try stack a few SQL LIKEs since you cannot use FULLTEXT.